# Clearinterval not working in ajaxrequest

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I made an ajax call and im calling a setInterval function which is working fine. Unfortunately when im trying to stop it it's not working.

```
    function test(str)
        {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                if (str=="?stage=3"){
                    test('?stage=4');
                } 
                if (str=="?stage=4"){
                     document.getElementById("main").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
 prog=window.clearInterval(prog);

                }else{
                    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;        
                }

            }
          else
          {
            if (str=="?stage=3"){
                var prog = self.setInterval( "ajaxrequest('progress_track.php', 'main')", 1000 );
            } 
        }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php"+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I remade my code because i found out that it calls somehow 3 times the setinveral function. Whit this code it only calls 2 times. I just dont understand why.

```
var prog = 0;
function test(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && str=="?stage=3")
    {
        test('?stage=4');   
    }else{
        if( str=="?stage=3"){
        prog = self.setInterval( "ajaxrequest('progress_track.php', 'main')", 1000 );   
        }
    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && str=="?stage=4")
    {
        prog=window.clearInterval(prog);    
    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && str!="?stage=4" && str!="?stage=3")
    {
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

But the cleariterval still not working.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem. Whit this code it never arrives in this state:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && str=="?stage=4")
    {
        prog=window.clearInterval(prog);    
    }
```

Now the only question is why not?

Comment: `xmlhttp` is a global variable, possibly colliding with other ajax calls.

Comment: it could be but what would be a solution for this?

Comment: define the variable at the top of your `test` function: `var xmlhttp;` so it is scoped to that function only.

Comment: When you run in the debugger, and put a breakpoint on the if statement in question, what are the values of `xmlhttp.readyState`, `xmlhttp.status` and `str` at that point?

Comment: Okay i made a brake point at that state. When i'm going step to step with the debugger everything is fine and it stops the script at this point. But when i'm doing it the same without the debugger its also reach this point but not stopping the setinterval script

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare "prog" at a higher scope.  You could move it outside of your function declaration:

```
var prog;
function test(str) {
  ...
  if (str=="?stage=3"){
    prog = self.setInterval( 
      "ajaxrequest('progress_track.php', 'main')", 1000 
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

The way you've got it right now, `prog` is undefined when you call `clearInterval()`

Comment: inside the function could work to, just under the "function test(str) {" line, less chans it colidate whit somthing else

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers i made the changes but it's still doesn't working out. I also cleared the browser cache

Comment: Can you run in a debugger (firebug or something) and see if prog is getting set, and if it is, is it still set when you get to your stage4 callback?

Comment: i tested it with firebug it is still set at stage4 but somehow it's skipping prog=window.clearInterval(prog); this line.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you're declaring the variable to keep the timer ID inside your function, yet you're trying to use it before it's defined.  When you are trying to clear it, the variable is not defined.  What you can do is define the variable outside and then use it.  Something like this:

```
var prog = 0;

function test(str)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            if (str=="?stage=3"){
                test('?stage=4');
            } 
            if (str=="?stage=4"){
                 document.getElementById("main").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
                 prog=window.clearInterval(prog);

            }else{
                document.getElementById("main").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;        
            }

        }
      else
      {
        if (str=="?stage=3"){
            prog = self.setInterval( "ajaxrequest('progress_track.php', 'main')", 1000 );
        } 
    }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php"+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You may also want to check whether it's 0 before clearing.  If it's 0 it means it's not set yet and it doesn't need to be cleared.

Comment: Aleks thank you for your answer unfortunately it doesnt working:S

Comment: i meant that the clearInteval is not stopping the setinteval function